# Outputting Arabic (Unicode) characters AS IS when using PHP json_encode

Tags: php, json, unicode, arabic

I'm using json_encode to encode Arabic (Unicode) text, that is converting each letter to a string like \u0627\u0644\u0633\u064a\u0627\u0631\u0627\u062a.

This (to me) is annoying and dramatically increases the size of output.

I need a simple solution to output the text properly without converting it to weird long characters like above.

My input array is:

```
$array = array(1 => 'اللغة', 2 => 'العربية', 3 => 'تحوّل إلى', 4 => 'جيسون');
```

The output I'm getting from json_encode:

```
{"1":"\u0627\u0644\u0644\u063a\u0629","2":"\u0627\u0644\u0639\u0631\u0628\u064a\u0629","3":"\u062a\u062d\u0648\u0651\u0644 \u0625\u0644\u0649","4":"\u062c\u064a\u0633\u0648\u0646"}
```

While I expect the result to be:

```
{"1":"اللغة","2":"العربية","3":"تحوّل إلى","4":"جيسون"}
```

Comment: I see why you've made this and appreciate your effort. But unfortunately this is not real question (Rather some kind of knowledge-base item) and therefore is not useful for the Q&A-Format of stackoverflow. If you could reformat it as a question, you could self-answer it after a while (or maybe someone comes up with an other, maybe better idea)

Comment: You are looking for the `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` option. Available since PHP 5.4 or use version 17 of upgradephp (test-up converted).

Comment: It appears to be a real question, since it has a real answer (Use `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`), and since the expected output is in fact valid JSON. (PHP being apparently over-zealous as to characters escaping.)

Comment: Throwing in my full agreement on the topic of `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` (but be aware that it's PHP 5.4+ only). And at the risk of offending a moderator I must say I thoroughly disagree with "those few more bytes don't really matter nowadays". Optimisation is a lost art, it seems.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for JSON and thus you get JSON: In JSON certain unicode characters are supposed to be represented in exactly this way: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627#section-2.5

Besides that, those few more bytes don't really matter nowadays.

Comment: Yes, I know the RFC says character needs to be encoded like \u0123 number, but still if I use the same string it will work fine.
A great [user contributed note here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#105789) suggests a solution for devs using PHP 5.3 emulating 5.4 upcoming **JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE**

Comment: Well, sorry but no, Arabic characters are valid as-is. Quoting the same document you referred to: "All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F)."

Answer (score 2):

Use JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE inside json_encode()

Answer (score 2):

```
json_encode($array , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```